# Strange behaviour of std::vector<{QString,int*}>

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following program:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    QString str;
    int *pointer;
    A(QString s) : str(s), pointer(0) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.emplace_back("111");
    v.emplace_back("222");
    v.emplace_back("333");
    v.emplace_back("444");
    v.emplace_back("555");
    for (const A &a : v)
        qDebug() << a.str;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ main.cpp -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core` (GCC version 8.1.1, Qt version 5.11.1, Arch Linux), it produces the following unexpected output:

```
""
""
""
""
"555"
```

It works, however, when using -O2 or clang++ or when explicitly requesting the default copy-constructor:

```
A(const A &b) = default;
```

What's wrong with the code? (Maybe something bad happens in the move operation when increasing the vector's size?)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. How is the QString class defined, especially the assignment operator and copy the constructor?

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-5) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq). Seems pretty straightforward to me. (The most obvious difference from std::string is that QString implements copy-on-write, so "copying" is a constant-time operation. But I don't see how that would be a problem.) You can find the source code of assignment [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp#n2176).

Comment: Prints all of them for me (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3).

Comment: Here (GCC 8.1.0; Qt 5.10.1, on Debian), it works with `-O3 -march=native` but fails with `-O3` alone.

Comment: Seems to be something wrong with the generated move-constructor.  If I add the copy constructor as you show, it works, but if I also add `A(A&& b) = default;` then it fails again.  And it works on GCC 7 regardless.  This is probably a bug, and should be reported.

Comment: Additional evidence for your hypothesis - calling `v.reserve(10)` before any construction will make it work.  Also, adding an explicit move constructor `A(A&& b)
        : str(std::move(b.str)), pointer(std::move(b.pointer))
    {}` doesn't change anything - but changing `str(std::move(b.str))` to `str(b.str)` does make it work.

Comment: In fact, ` -O1 -fstrict-aliasing -ftree-loop-vectorize` is enough to make it fail. If it's a bug, how to tell whether to report it to GCC or to Qt?

Comment: I've reported it to the Qt Bug Tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87665

Thanks for the help!